# transition not working for transform on class removal

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have written this code :

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.page-holder').children[0].children[0].classList.remove("enable");
}, 2000);
```

```css
@keyframes appearPageShower {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.each-page {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.each-page .backgroundColor {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.each-page .backgroundColor.enable {
  animation: appearPageShower 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-holder">
  <div class="each-page">
    <div class="backgroundColor enable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The animation works perfectly, the problem is that, after removing "enable" class from the div, I suppose transiton would work but instead it pops out by the transform. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you want to happen after the animation finishes? I see it works but I'm not exactly sure what you want to happen afterwards.

Comment: @broderick I want ```transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;``` these two styles work on this div by *backgroundColor* class, after removing *enable* class from it.

Answer (score 0):

use `animation-fill-mode`

```
.each-page .backgroundColor.enable {
  animation: appearPageShower 1s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

animation-fill-mode keeps the final styling after animation ends...

Comment: not what I was looking for, I changed my perspective toward the problem and solved it in a different way though. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`animation-fill-mode: forwards;` works for getting the blue to stay in place after it falls down, but the following also does the job:

in .backgroundColor:

```
.each-page .backgroundColor {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*transform: translateY(100%); Change to below*/ 
  transform: translateY(0);
  /*animation: appearPageShower 1s ease; Note this out or remove*/
}
```

I've tested this with the script noted out and with the script in and it works either way. I would remove the script unless you have further plans for it.

Although it's entirely valid to call the animation in .backgroundColor, it's redundant and unnecessary in both css classes.

By calling `translateY(100%);` I suspect the blue rectangle is going (1 * width) past the black rectangle.

Comment: not what I was looking for, I changed my perspective toward the problem and solved it in a different way though. thanks